# Different output for equivalent code between Matlab and Julia

Tags: matlab, julia, output, ode

I have a working Matlab algorithm for the evolution of a pulse via solving the 1D wave equation. I know the code works and I can see the pulse traveling to the sides and bouncing off the walls, when plotting; but when I translate the corresponding steps as Julia code, however, the results are completely different for the same set of inputs. I insert a simple pulse that should propagate across a string in both directions but that isn't exactly the result that I'm getting in Julia... and I don't know why.

Could anybody help point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you,

This is the corresponding Julia code:

```julia
using Plots,OhMyREPL

    #-solving a PDE.
    
    #NOTE: DOMAIN
    # space
    Lx = 20
    dx = 0.1
    nx = Int(trunc(Lx/dx))
    x  = range(0,Lx,nx)#0:dx:Lx-1
    
    
    #NOTE: TIME
    T = 10
    
    #NOTE: Field variable.
    #-variables.
    wn     = zeros(nx)#-current value.
    wnm1   = wn#zeros(nx)#-w at time n-1.
    wnp1   = wn#zeros(nx)#-w at time n+1.
    # wnp1[1:end] = wn[1:end]#-w at time n+1.
    
    #NOTE: PARAMETERS.
    CFL  = 1#-CFL = c.dt/dx
    c   = 1#-the propagation speed.
    dt  = CFL * dx/c    
    
    #     #NOTE: Initial Conditions.
    wn[49] = 0.1; wn[50] = 0.2;  wn[51] = 0.1
    wnp1[1:end] = wn[1:end]#--assumption that they are being equaled.
    wnp1 = wn#--assumption that they are being equaled.
    
    
    run = true
    if run == true
        #NOTE: Initial Conditions.
        wn[49] = 0.1; wn[50] = 0.2;  wn[51] = 0.1
        wnp1 = wn#--wnp1[1:end] = wn[1:end]#--assumption that they are being equaled.
        
        # NOTE: Time stepping loop.
        t = 0
        while t<T
            #-apply reflecting boundary conditions.
            wn[1]=0.0;wn[end]=0.0
    
            #NOTE: solution::
            global t = t+dt
            global wnm1 = wn; global wn = wnp1#-save CURRENT and PREVIOUS arrays.
            for i=2:nx-1
                global wnp1[i] = 2*wn[i] - wnm1[i] + CFL^2 * ( wn[i+1] -2*wn[i] + wn[i-1]  )
            end
    
        end
        plot(x,wnp1, yrange=[-0.2,0.2])
    end
```

Only one peak

[image: Only one peak]

This is the corresponding Matlab code:

```matlab
%Domain
%Space.
Lx = 20;
dx = 0.1;
nx = fix(Lx/dx);
x  = linspace(0,Lx,nx);

%Time
T = 10;

%Field Variables

wn = zeros(nx,1);
wnm1 = wn;
wnp1 = wn;
%Parameters...
CFL = 1;
c = 1;
dt = CFL*dx/c;


%Initial conditions
wn(49:51) = [0.1 0.2 0.1];    
wnp1(:) = wn(:);




run = true;
if run == true
    %Initial conditions
    wn(49:51) = [0.1 0.2 0.1];    
    wnp1(:) = wn(:);
    
    %Time stepping loop
    t = 0;
    while t<T      
      %Reflecting boundary conditions:
      wn([1 end]) = 0.0;
      %Solution:
      t=t+dt;
      wnm1=wn;wn = wnp1;%-save current and previous arrays.
      for i=2:nx-1
        wnp1(i) = 2*wn(i) - wnm1(i) + CFL^2 * (  wn(i+1) - 2*wn(i) + wn(i-1)   );
      endfor    
    end
    plot(x,wnp1)
end
```

Two peaks, as it should be.

[image: Two peaks, as it should be.]

If anybody could point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Just a thought. In Julia, `A = B` doesn't do a copy from B to A, it makes them the same object. You would have to opt in to a copy using `A = copy(B`), or similar. What does this do? `global wnm1 = wn;`

Comment: BOY - oh, boy. Gosh... did just THAT in line 53 and... it *actually solved my problem. * The output is now the exact same... whew. Thank you so much. I've learned something new today - again: thank you, so, so much.

Comment: @Francis_King, maybe you could post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @StefanKarpinski: OK, I'll do that

Answer (score 4):

Julia arrays are designed to be fast. So, when an array is assigned to another array, the default behaviour is make the two arrays the same - same variable address, occupying the same area of memory. Editing one array does the exact same edit on the other array:

```
 x = [1,2,3]
 y = x

 x[1] = 7

 # x is [7,2,3]
 # y is [7,2,3] also
```

To copy data from one array to another an explicit copy is required:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = copy(x)

x[1] = 7

# x is [7,2,3]
# y is [1,2,3] still
```

The same thing happens with Python lists:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = x

x[0] = 7 # Julia indexes arrays 1+, Python indexes lists 0+

# x is [7,2,3]
# y is [7,2,3] also
```

It is done this way to minimise the effort of unnecessary copying, which can be expensive.

The upshot is that if the code is running but gives the wrong result, a possible cause is assigning an array when a copy is intended.

The question author indicated that this was indeed the cause of the code's behaviour.